# Pytest-benchmark: precomputing test data

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-benchmark

Could you tell me please if precomputation of test input data in the same script is a valid approach, and if that would not affect the benchmarking procedure (i.e. timing)?

E.g., in `script.py`

```
def compute_inputs():
    #some computations
    #return inputs

INPUTS = compute_inputs()

def something(some_arg):
    # code to be benchmarked

def test_my_stuff(benchmark):
    # benchmark something
    result = benchmark(something)
```

And then run it like this:

```
pytest script.py
```

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; According to the *pytest-benchmark* [documentation](https://pytest-benchmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it only benchmarks a callable that you pass to it. So in theory, any variables you've precomputed before the call to the function you benchmark, **will not affect the result** (timing).

We can make an example and see it in practice:

```py
def something():
    time.sleep(1)
    return 123


def test_my_stuff(benchmark):
    result = benchmark(something)

    assert result == 123
```

The example above sleeps for 1 second, so we'd expect the runtime to be about that. And it's runtime is indeed ~1 second:

```bash
------------------------------------------- benchmark: 1 tests ------------------------------------------
Name (time in s)        Min     Max    Mean  StdDev  Median     IQR  Outliers     OPS  Rounds  Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test_my_stuff        1.0005  1.0050  1.0031  0.0019  1.0028  0.0032       1;0  0.9969       5           1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now let's try a case, where we precompute some values:

```py
def compute_inputs():
    time.sleep(1)
    return 123

INPUT = compute_inputs()

def something():
    time.sleep(1)
    return INPUT


def test_my_stuff(benchmark):
    result = benchmark(something)

    assert result == 123
```

Here, we can treat `INPUT` as a precomputed input. It takes one second to produce `INPUT`, so we could expect the total runtime to be 2 seconds. But as you can see in the output, *pytest-benchmark* ignores this precomputation and only counts the callables that are executed inside the `benchmark` fixture:

```bash
------------------------------------------- benchmark: 1 tests ------------------------------------------
Name (time in s)        Min     Max    Mean  StdDev  Median     IQR  Outliers     OPS  Rounds  Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test_my_stuff        1.0008  1.0050  1.0030  0.0019  1.0038  0.0033       2;0  0.9970       5           1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```